# Improve query performance when joining a small and a large table and using a where clause on the small table

Tags: join, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have two tables one having 2 Million records (Employees) and other having around thousand records (Cities). I am joining the tables based on id (City_Id). City_Id is the primary key of the Cities table and I have an index on the City_Id column of the Employees table.

I run the following queries on these tables

1) `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES, CITIES WHERE EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID=CITIES.CITY_ID and EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NAME='XYZ';`

2) `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES, CITIES WHERE EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID=CITIES.CITY_ID and CITIES.CITY_CLASS='ABC';`

I also have indexes on EMPLOYEE_NAME of EMPLOYEES table and CITY_CLASS of the CITIES table.

The first query executes very fast, but the second one is very slow. Can you please let me know what needs to be done to make the second one run faster?

Comment: Please attach execution plans of both queries to your question.

Comment: Is there an index on EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID ? If no, then create it, and check the query speed.

Answer (score 1):

**Go For Right Index**

Let me build your schema here

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2 ( 50 ),
                    CITY_ID NUMBER ( 2 ),
                    DUMMYCOL VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) );

CREATE TABLE CITIES ( CITY_CLASS VARCHAR2 ( 10 ),
                  CITY_ID NUMBER ( 2 ),
                  DUMMYCOL VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) );
```

Indexes as you mentioned

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_T1
    ON EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_NAME );

CREATE INDEX IDX_T2
    ON CITIES ( CITY_CLASS );
```

Simulating the number of rows

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'EMPLOYEES',
                            NUMROWS  => 2000000 );
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'CITIES',
                            NUMROWS  => 1000 );
END;
/
```

Trying your first query

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON
SELECT
      *
FROM
      EMPLOYEES,
      CITIES
WHERE
      EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY_ID
      AND EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'XYZ';
```

**Note**: Query is using IDX_T1 for faster retreival and Employees table is accessed through index 
Hence it is faster

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=27 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   1    0    HASH JOIN (Cost=27 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   2    1      TABLE ACCESS FULL REALSPIRITUALS.CITIES (Cost=21 Card=1 K Bytes=97 K)
   3    1      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.EMPLOYEES (Cost=5 Card=20 K Bytes=1 M)
   4    3        INDEX RANGE SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.IDX_T1 (Cost=1 Card=8 K)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        203  recursive calls
          0  spare statistic 3
          0  gcs messages sent
         29  db block gets from cache
          0  physical reads direct (lob)
          0  queue position update
          0  queue single row
          0  queue ocp pages
          0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
          0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
          0  rows processed
```

Your second query now

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON

SELECT
      *
FROM
      EMPLOYEES,
      CITIES
WHERE
      EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY_ID
      AND CITIES.CITY_CLASS = 'ABC';
```

Note: Query is using IDX_T2 for faster retreival but Employees table is having a Full Table Scan 
Hence it is slower

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=52 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   1    0    HASH JOIN (Cost=52 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   2    1      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.CITIES (Cost=5 Card=10 Bytes=1000)
   3    2        INDEX RANGE SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.IDX_T2 (Cost=1 Card=4)
   4    1      TABLE ACCESS FULL REALSPIRITUALS.EMPLOYEES (Cost=38 Card=2 M Bytes=190 M)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  spare statistic 3
          0  gcs messages sent
          0  db block gets from cache
          0  physical reads direct (lob)
          0  queue position update
          0  queue single row
          0  queue ocp pages
          0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
          0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
          0  rows processed
```

Now I am adding an index

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_T3
    ON EMPLOYEES ( CITY_ID );
```

Retrying your second query

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON

SELECT
      *
FROM
      EMPLOYEES,
      CITIES
WHERE
      EMPLOYEES.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY_ID
      AND CITIES.CITY_CLASS = 'ABC';
```

**Note**: FTS is avoided and the query is using the index for retrieval

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=5 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   1    0    NESTED LOOPS
   2    1      NESTED LOOPS (Cost=5 Card=20 K Bytes=3 M)
   3    2        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.CITIES (Cost=5 Card=10 Bytes=1000)
   4    3          INDEX RANGE SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.IDX_T2 (Cost=1 Card=4)
   5    2        INDEX RANGE SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.IDX_T3 (Cost=0 Card=1)
   6    1      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.EMPLOYEES (Cost=0 Card=2 K Bytes=195 K)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  spare statistic 3
          0  gcs messages sent
          0  db block gets from cache
          0  physical reads direct (lob)
          0  queue position update
          0  queue single row
          0  queue ocp pages
          0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
          0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
          0  rows processed
```

This should be faster :) 
**In general to speed up queries, always go for index only on the columns used in the where clause**